# Почему обнуляются значения сохраненные через NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development

При выполнении открывания контроллера сразу после сохранения значений переменной, значения сохраняются коректно, а если два раза подряд запускать апп и сохранять значения без захода на контроллер вывода значений, то при заходе на этот контроллер переменная снова принимает значение единицы

контроллер вывода значения

```
var shareCount = (Int)()// находится за классом контроллера

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("shareCount") != nil  {
        shareCount = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("shareCount") as! Int
    }
    print("shareCount = \(shareCount)")
}
```

контроллер сохранения

```
//...
let appImage = UIImage(named: "myImage")
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [appImage!], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
   if (!completed) {
       shareCount += 1
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(shareCount, forKey: "shareCount")
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
       return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем хранить Int в Object? И не лучше избавиться от промежуточной переменной?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("shareCount = \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("shareCount"))")
}
```

...

```
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if (!completed) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(defaults.integerForKey("shareCount") + 1, forKey: "shareCount")
        defaults.synchronize()
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Из-за отсутствия опыта  не допер